# How to make android animation like that in Jelly

Tags: android, android-animation

I really like the card draging animation in Jelly http://jelly.co/ or similar animation in http://www.sobrr.me/

Which contains a single card view, when you "throw" the card, next card is coming into the view.

Could anyone give me some idea about how to make an Android animation similar to those?
Many Thanks

Comment: @AlokNair plz keep ur suggestion with you ..dont teach me what is usefull and what not

Comment: @user3916770 hey animation kinda did u tried something?

Comment: @AlokNair i dont want to waste time argue here ..hv deleted my comments i hope i wont hear anything from u in futyre

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can implement such a feature by following this link. It is a library to implement such animations, also known famously as Tinder Like Animations ...

https://github.com/kikoso/Swipeable-Cards

http://grishma102.blogspot.ca/2014/04/tinder-app-like-control-with-animation.html

Hope this helps :)